# why does left go faster than right for my pygame sprite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i have a sprite that represents my players for my game in pygame but both of them move to left faster than the right.

important parts of my code:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,
                 name,
                 width,
                 height,
                 image=None,
                 keys=dict(left=pygame.K_a, right=pygame.K_d, up=pygame.K_w, down=pygame.K_s),
                 jump_height=2.55,
                 move_speed=1.5,
                 pos=(0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        if image is None:
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
        else:
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
            self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
            self.image.fill(image)
        self.keys = keys
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.pos = pos
        self.rect.topleft = pos
        self.VX = 0
        self.VY = 0
        self.jump_height = jump_height
        self.move_speed = move_speed
        self.haveJumped = False
        self.wins = 0

    def move(self):
        self.VX = 0.0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[self.keys["left"]]:
            self.VX = -self.move_speed
            if self.rect.left > 0:
                self.rect.left += self.VX

        if pressed[self.keys["right"]]:
            self.VX = self.move_speed
            if self.rect.right < windowWidth:
                self.rect.right += self.VX
```

would someone please be able to tell me why my players move faster to the left and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Rect docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers.

Pygame's Rect is meant to deal with pixels and your `move_speed` is `1.5`, so

```
if pressed[self.keys["left"]]:
    self.VX = -self.move_speed
    if self.rect.left > 0:
        self.rect.left += self.VX
```

Moves your rect `2` to the left, and

```
if pressed[self.keys["right"]]:
    self.VX = self.move_speed
    if self.rect.right < windowWidth:
        self.rect.right += self.VX
```

Moves your rect `1` to the right.

You should use some other variable in your class to store your object's position. You can make use of the `pos` attribute that's already there:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,
                 name,
                 width,
                 height,
                 image=None,
                 keys=dict(left=pygame.K_a, right=pygame.K_d, up=pygame.K_w, down=pygame.K_s),
                 jump_height=2.55,
                 move_speed=1.5,
                 pos=(0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        if image is None:
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
        else:
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
            self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
            self.image.fill(image)
        self.keys = keys
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.pos = pos
        self.rect.topleft = pos
        self.VX = 0
        self.VY = 0
        self.jump_height = jump_height
        self.move_speed = move_speed
        self.haveJumped = False
        self.wins = 0

    def move(self):
        self.VX = 0.0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[self.keys["left"]]:
            self.VX = -self.move_speed
            if self.pos[0] > 0:
                self.pos[0] += self.VX

        if pressed[self.keys["right"]]:
            self.VX = self.move_speed
            if (self.pos[0] + self.width) < windowWidth:
                self.pos[0] += self.VX
```

But note that you'll need to change your rendering code accordingly.

Comment: this fixed the speed issue but now my players will not go up and down in my other functions. would you by chance know why?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on how you're tracking your objects' vertical position and on how you're rendering your objects.